# Android - finding an ImageView then setting its visibility

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a grid of ImageViews (10x10) which are stars. I'm trying to randomise a coordinate, and to then make that star visible. My XML for my MainActivity is:

```
<TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="invisible">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/star_a1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/star_b1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/star_c1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" />
```

etc. I have set the visibility as invisible. In order to find the ID and to then change the visibility, I have done:

```
int starID = getResources().getIdentifier(coord, "id", getPackageName());
ImageView target = (ImageView)findViewById(starID);
target.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

However, when running my app, I get the error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                  at com.example.localadmin.myapplication1.MainActivity.OnClick(MainActivity.java:73)
```

Line 73 being "target.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);".

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep track of your View ids in a static array like this

```
static int[] stars = {
        R.id.star_a1, R.id.star_b1, R.id.star_c1,
        R.id.star_a2, R.id.star_b2, R.id.star_c2   // as many ids as you need...
};
```

Then you could choose a random star and set its visibility like this

```
int index = new Random().nextInt(stars.length);         // choose a random array index
int id = stars[index];                                  // grab the element from the array
ImageView chosenStar = (ImageView) findViewById(id);    // find the right view
chosenStar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                 // make the chosen view visible
```

That could of course be done with fewer lines of code, but I wanted to make each step clear. One other thing: I don't think you should be making the table rows in your xml layout invisible. And then your random stars should appear!

Comment: Was hoping I wouldn't have to initialise all those IDs but if that's the only way then that's fine - Thanks!